# Java accessing an Arraylist to compare it to a String parameter?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am working on a parking ticket simulator and I am trying to write a method that uses the car license plate as a parameter which searches the collection of officerslist and returns the number of tickets issued to a specific car. I have these classes

```
public class ParkedCar {


private String ownerName;
private String carMake;
private String licensePlateNumber;
private int modelYear;
private int numberOfMinutesParked;

public class ParkingTicket {
    private String officerName;
    private String officerBadgeNumber;
    private String ticketNumber;
    private String carLicensePlateNumber;
    private double fineAmountInCAD;

public class PoliceOfficer
{ 

    private String officerName;
    private String officerBadgeNumber;
    private ArrayList<ParkingTicket> ticketList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class PoliceDepartment
{ 

    private String address;
    private ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> officerList;
```

my method looks like this at the moment

```
public int totalParkingTicketCountOfACar

int totalCount = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
        ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> carTickets = new ArrayList<PoliceOfficer>();

    Iterator<PoliceOfficer> it = carTickets.iterator();

     while(it.hasNext()){

            PoliceOfficer carticket = it.next();


         if(officerList.equalsIgnoreCase(licensePlateNumber)){
             totalCount++;
            }
        }

          return totalCount;
```

I am not sure how to go about having the all the officers in the list and compare it to that license plate to get the number of tickets issued to a specific car? any help is much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `PoliceDepartment` has a list of `PoliceOfficer`.
Each `PoliceOfficer` has a list of `ParkingTicket`.
Each `ParkingTicket` is for one `ParkedCar`.

You want to iterate through all the `PoliceOfficer`'s. For each one you want to iterate through his `ParkingTicket`'s. For each `ParkingTicket` whose `carLicensePlateNumber` matches your parameter, you want to increment a running total.

```java
public int getTotalCarTickets(String license) {
    int total = 0;
    PoliceDepartment pd = // However you obtain it.
    for (PoliceOfficer po : pd.getOfficerList()) {
        for (ParkingTicket ticket : po.getTicketList()) {
            if (ticket.getCarLicensePlateNumber().equals(license)) {
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I would've been stuck for hours